# How to create a new DataFrame repeating rows using indexes from original DF

Tags: python, pandas, loops, database-indexes

I have a DataFrame of generated random agents. However, I want to expand them to match the population I am looking for, so I need to repeat rows, according to my sampled indexes.

Here is a loop code that is taking forever:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, 1, 2]})    
sampled_indexes = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a'])
for i, idx in enumerate(sampled_indexes):
    new_df.loc[i] = df.loc[idx]
```

Then, the original DataFrame:

```
df
   a
0  0
1  1
2  2
```

gives me the result of an enlarged new dataframe

```
new_df
   a
0  0
1  0
2  1
3  1
4  2
5  2
6  2
```

So, this loop is too slow with a DataFrame that has 34,000 or more rows (takes forever).

How can I do this simpler and faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reindex the dataframe with `sampled_indexes`, then reset the index.

```
df.reindex(sampled_indexes).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do `DataFrame.merge`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, 1, 2]})
sampled_indexes = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]

print( df.merge(pd.DataFrame({'a': sampled_indexes})) )
```

Prints:

```
   a
0  0
1  0
2  1
3  1
4  2
5  2
6  2
```